# Need help with regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I am trying to index some content from a series of .html's that share the same format.

So I get a lot of lines like this: `<a href="meh">[18] blah blah blah < a...`

And the idea is to extract the number (18) and the text next to it (blah...). Furthermore, I know that every qualifying line will start with `">` and end with either `<a` or `</p`. The issue stems from the need to keep all other htmHTML tags as part of the text (`<i>`, `<u>`, etc.).

So then I have something like this:

```
$docString = file_get_contents("http://whatever.com/some.htm");
$regex="/\">\ [(.*?)\ ] (<\/a>)(.) *?(<)/";
preg_match_all($regex,$docString,$match);
```

Let's look at `$regex` for a sec. Ignore it's spaces, I just put them here because else some characters disappear. I specify that it will start with `">`. Then I do the numbers inside the `[]` thing. Then I single out the `</a>`. So far so good.

At the end, I do a `(.)*?(<)`. This is the turning point. By leaving the last bit, `(<)` like that, The text will be interrupted when an underline or italics tag is found. However, if I put `(<a|</p)` the resulting array ends up empty. I've tried changing that to only `(<a)`, but it seems that 2 characters mess up the whole ting.

What can I do? I've been struggling with this all day.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) is your friend. [Don't use regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 1):

Something like `/">\[(.*)\](.*)(?:<(?:a|\/p))/` seems to work fine for given your example and description. Perhaps adding non-capturing subpatterns does it? Please provide a counterexample wherein this doesn't work for you.

Though I agree that RegEx isn't a parser, it sounds like what you're looking for is part of a regularly behaved string - which is exactly what RegEx is strong at.

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, using a regex to parse HTML is not very easy. This is because HTML is not particularly regular.

I suggest using an XML parser such as PHP's [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Create an object, then use the [loadHTMLFile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) method to open the file. Extract your `a` tags with [getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), and then extract the content as the NodeValue property.

It might look like

```
// Create a DomDocument object 
$html = new DOMDocument(); 

// Load the url's contents into the DOM 
$html->loadHTMLFile("http://whatever.com/some.htm"); 

// make an array to hold the text 
$anchors = array(); 

//Loop through the a tags and store them in an array 
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) { 
    $anchors[] = $link->nodeValue;
    }
```

One alternative to this style of XML/HTML parser is [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). The documentation on their page should do a good job of explaining how to extract the tags. If you know jQuery, the interface may seem more natural.